# Try catch in asp.net when to use it?

Tags: asp.net

i an new in asp.net(vb) and I build a simple project with SQL connection (insert-update-delete)to database.

When I must use try catch? 
inside every command or in page load only?

Comment: show some effort what you tried

Answer (score 1):

An exception is a problem that arises during the execution of a program. A C# exception is a response to an exceptional circumstance that arises while a program is running, such as an attempt to divide by zero.

Exceptions provide a way to transfer control from one part of a program to another. C# exception handling is built upon four keywords: try, catch, finally and throw.

**try**: A try block identifies a block of code for which particular exceptions will be activated. It's followed by one or more catch blocks.

**catch**: A program catches an exception with an exception handler at the place in a program where you want to handle the problem. The catch keyword indicates the catching of an exception.

**finally**: The finally block is used to execute a given set of statements, whether an exception is thrown or not thrown. For example, if you open a file, it must be closed whether an exception is raised or not.

**throw**: A program throws an exception when a problem shows up. This is done using a throw keyword.

```
try
{
   // statements causing exception
}
catch( ExceptionName e1 )
{
   // error handling code
}
catch( ExceptionName e2 )
{
   // error handling code
}
catch( ExceptionName eN )
{
   // error handling code
}
finally
{
   // statements to be executed
}
```